# How can I add a border to an element while the mouse is over it without changing its position?

Tags: html, css

When I add border to an fontawesome icon, when mouse gets over it, its position starts changing a little bit. I don't know why this happens. When mouse gets over the the icon, a border appears but it does changes the position of element a little bit too. I just want the border to be appeared not anything else.
It's like by adding border, the width and height of the element changes.

```css
#exit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#exit div {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    margin: 1;
}

#exit div:hover {
    border: 4px solid #f4efde;
}

#exit div:active {
    background-color: #f4efde;
    color: #0f0f0f;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="exit">
    <div>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

[the image of the related element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7672.png)

Comment: I slightly edited your question to embed your code inside a real workable snippet. I added fontawesome and did a fair guess on how the html was supposed to look like. Does it match with your real scenario? I followed the css rules you included for my guess.

Comment: Element width = width + border size + padding. So adding a border changes the width (and/or height) of the element. Add `box-sizing: border-box` to your css. This keeps everything inside the original width/height. See [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: Hi bro. Thank you for the edit. yeah the problem is now clear. I've already added 'box-sizing: border-box' but it's still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to also have a border in the not-hovered state but that will be invisible. One line added to your code below.

```
#exit div {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    margin: 1;
    border: 4px solid transparent;  <------ Like this

}

#exit div:hover {
    border: 4px solid #f4efde;
}
```

Comment: small thing - since the type and size of the border are already specified and don't change on the hover - you can just replace the border-color attribute... #exit div:hover {
    border-color: #f4efde;}... without redeclaring the others

Answer (score 0):

As @Cutey from Cute Code mentioned - one solution is to apply a transparent border which then gets a color on the hover - but an alternative is to apply an **outline** on the hover. The difference is that the border does affect the box-model so causes the shift in the element, while the outline does not affect the box-model and is added around the element without shifting it.

The outline-offset can be a positive or negative number to control the outline relative to the div.

```css
#exit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#exit div {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    margin: 1;

}

#exit div:hover {
    outline: 4px solid #f4efde; // I added this
    outline-offset: 0 // I also added this just so you can experiement with te offset to your liking
}

#exit div:active {
    background-color: #f4efde;
    color: #0f0f0f;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="exit">
    <div>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```